# VSCode 0.3 can't find runtime 'node' on path

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I just upgraded from 0.1 of vscode to 0.3. Now I'm getting an error when I run the debugger "can't find runtime 'node' on path". I have iojs v2.3.0 running on OSX 10.10.3. 
I installed iojs using nvm, so it is possible that node is not in the path, but I can type "node" in terminal and get a repl.

Comment: The solution for me was to use the real nodejs.org installer to put the latest version of node on my machine. I can still use nvm to control what is in play.

Answer (score 8):

## NODE PATH FOR VSCODE VERSION 0.7.0

---

I'm running Ubuntu GNU/Linux 12.04.5 LTS.  Before VSCode 0.7.0 I would leave my node path to the default found on the PATH in the launch.json file:

```
// Workspace relative or absolute path to the runtime executable to       be used. Default is the runtime executable on the PATH.
        "runtimeExecutable": null,
```

However, after the update to 0.7.0, I started receiving `'can't find runtime on "node" PATH'` errors even though node was on my PATH.

```
18:25:37 ツ gjsmith3rd@DV7:~ 
$echo $PATH
/usr/bin:...//Plus the rest of the PATH
18:25:44 ツ gjsmith3rd@DV7:~ 

18:21:36 ツ gjsmith3rd@DV7:~ 
$which node
/usr/bin/node
18:21:43 ツ gjsmith3rd@DV7:~
```

I changed my launch.json to:

```
// Workspace relative or absolute path to the runtime executable to be used. Default is the runtime executable on the PATH.
        "runtimeExecutable": "/user/bin/node",
```

Now all is working fine.  The actual path is `/usr/bin/` and the executable is `node`.

Comment: Another way while you're in Unix to find the value for the value for runtimeExecutable in node is to use the output from `which node` in your terminal. For example in my case I was helping someone using nvm and their node executable was shown to be somewhere like `/usr/local/bin/node` after using the `which node` command.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, please restart your computer .. is likely to be solved. I have a similar problem, my problem was solved by restarting the operating system.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38414254/4746570

Answer (score 0):

This should not be related to your VSCode update. 
Reinstalling node should fix the issue or explicitly adding your node runtime to PATH.

Comment: I switched to node 0.12.5 and I have the same issue. My path is jim$ echo $PATH
/Users/jim/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: If I run the 0.1 version the debugger picks up things just fine.

Comment: I had the similar issue. I had 0.12.7 node in my PATH but  visual studio code gives me an error : can't find runtime 'node' on PATH.

Comment: It would be nice to not to hardcode NVM paths but using nvm-based nodejs more easily