# Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH - Visual Studio Code and Node.js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

With a downloaded and installed version of Visual Studio Code 1.2.1, and a 64bit version of node.exe msi placed in my working directory (I am assuming that is correct), how do we add node and npm command line tools to be on our PATH? I am confused in understanding that statement. Where and how do we implement that? I am quoting this requirement directly from the top of this resource page - https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/nodejs

As a result of my current situation, I set a break-point in an app.js file. And when I hit F5, it tells me...

```
Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH
```

I am completely lost in understanding and fixing this issue in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: You should already have `node` and `npm` under PATH when installed properly. What OS are you using, and how did you install them?

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought.  I'm on Windows 10.   I went here -https://nodejs.org/en/download/ and downloaded the windows binary into my working folder.  I then use the Command Line from within VSC to check if node --help works, and it does.  But when I hit F5 to debug a .js file, I get this error. If i missed a step, please correct me.  Thanks

Comment: Just in case other people have my problem: quitting and reopening fixed this for me.

Comment: Restarting VS Code works, but the issue resurfaces time to time. How do I make this no longer an issue? I don't want to restart vs code and lose my typing history in some cases.

Comment: Same thing happened to me after updating the MacOS system update, as others pointed out restarting the VSCode worked.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To follow up, I just ran into this as well.  When I installed Node.js there was an option that said Add to PATH (Available After Restart).  Seems like Windows just needs a restart to make things work.

Comment: What about portable setup without adding node to the PATH, is there anyway to deal with that, seems a terrible restriction to me.]

Comment: This was my problem.  I avoided a restart by starting a new command prompt and launching vs code from the command prompt

Comment: Configure PATH required restart on windows (which is mentioned in installation wizard)

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: @Perposterer Wow, that worked (closing VSC, then running `code .` in the terminal to open it). Crazyiness. But it's only temporary. After I closed VSC and opened it in the normal way, the original problems reappeared (of nvm `node` not being in the Path).

Answer (score 251):

On OSX and VSCode <s>1.56.2</s> 1.84.2 all I had to do was to close and restart VSCode and the problem went away.

Before you despair give that a try.

Comment: I had to re-run `Shell command: Install 'code' command in PATH.` before restarting VSCode: (CMD+SHIFT+P and start typing command name)

Comment: This is correct (for my case). And sadly, I've run into this mulitple times and I keep coming back to your answer. Thanks @David

Comment: Seems like a recent bug.  This solved it for me on OSX Catalina

Comment: Wow, really. This worked for the VSCode plugin jest-runner.

Comment: I tried restarting VSCode and that didnt work for me. Restarting my computer worked. I'm also on MacOS big sur on an M1 Mac

Comment: I had to restart my computer to make it work as well

Comment: While restarting VSCode works, it reoccurs from time to time. After restarting you lose your history and can no longer undo. It's a pretty annoying bug.

Comment: Make sure to completely quit the application (by right click->quit on the Dock) and not just click the red close button.

Comment: No need to restart the computer, just run: `Code: Restart to Update`

Comment: For me the trick was to disable auto-attach before installing node with nvm (nvm install was freezing due to the auto-attach error)

Comment: Lifesaver here, I was just about to do drastic things before this. This bug appeared for me after Code automatically reopened after a restart, so maybe there's a race condition, and it opened before something else was ready? I don't know, but a quick restart of Code got everything back working right. Thank you

Comment: Why hasn't this bug been fixed?

Comment: That helps a lot.

Answer (score 108):

first run below commands as super user
`sudo code . --user-data-dir='.'`
it will open the visual code studio import the folder of your project and set the launch.json as below

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app/release/web.js",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"
            ],
            "runtimeExecutable": "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node"
        }
    ]
}
```

path of runtimeExecutable will be output of `"which node"` command.

Run the server in debug mode.

Comment: Genius. Also to mention, its a good practice to install node using nvm.

Comment: Got this after running: " sudo: code: command not found"'

Comment: It's 2024 and I just tried this and it created all sorts of bad things in my working directory.  I would say don't do this.

Comment: This is not a good recommendation to run vscode in `sudo`.

Answer (score 46):

Quick fix that works for me. Navigate to the root directory of your folder from command line (cmd). then once you are on your root directory, type:

```
code .
```

Then, press enter. Note the ".", don't forget it. Now try to debug and see if you get the same error.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!
Can you explain more?

Comment: If for example, you use nvm, running vscode from your current terminal profile (code .) will inherit from it the nvm configuration you probably have configured in .bashrc or .zshrc that points to the correct node binary

Comment: Thank you this was the only thing that worked for me

Comment: See related comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823194/cannot-find-runtime-node-on-path-visual-studio-code-and-node-js#comment136570092_38414254

Answer (score 29):

## Apply a Default Node Version via NVM

I'm using macOS Big Sur and setting the default version via `nvm` fixed this for me by running this command: `nvm alias default 16` (change `16` to the version you want as your default).

Note that `node` worked fine in the terminal for me (both with zsh and bash) but not when running via the vscode debugger and I already had the following config in both ~/.zshrc and ~/.bash_profile to load in `nvm`:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

It wasn't until I set the default Node version that vscode would launch node targets just fine.

Comment: don't forget to restart vscode afterwards

Comment: NVM has been my go-to for testing purposes between versions.

Comment: just doing `nvm alias default 16` in my case did the trick with a VSCode restart

Comment: Seems this works for me. Not sure why node worked in terminal. But code can't recognize it. Waste quite some time to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 27):

I did `which node` on my terminal:
`/usr/local/bin/node`

and then i added 
`"runtimeExecutable": "/usr/local/bin/node"` in my json file.

Comment: which json file?

Comment: @captainblack launch.json

Answer (score 14):

For me, the `node` binary is in `PATH` and I can run it from the terminal (iTerm or Terminal), and the Terminal apps are set to use `zsh`

If you are on a **Mac, with iTerm and Zsh**, please use the following VSCode settings for Node to work.

After this change, you can get rid of this line from your `launch.json` config file. (the debug settings in VSCode)

```json
    "runtimeExecutable": "/usr/local/bin/node"
```

If this doesn't work, make sure you choose the default shell as `zsh`. To do this,

- Open the command palette using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- Look for the `Terminal: Select Default Shell` command
  [image]
- Select `zsh` from the options
  [image]

Answer (score 10):

So node got kicked out of path. you can do

```
       SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%
```

Or simply reinstall node to fix this. which ever you think is easiest for you

Comment: Thanks for the quick tip!  If I set path, do I write out that exact line out in my command prompt? or within a file?  thanks for the direction on this.

Comment: This can be written via command line, just be careful as you might need double quotes in the path

Comment: This is so funny - sense 6:00pm last night, I put my windows 10 laptop to sleep.  woke it up this morning at 8:44am and made another attempt to F5 my javascript file.  And now the debugger works.  Looks like the path was off like you said, but it appears the application corrected itself...?  strange.

Comment: the Node to be installed is the application (from setup in nodejs.org), don't confuse with vscode extension (is not an extension).

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue and in my case it was a problem with a *vs code* extension. Try running code as:

```
$ code --disable-extensions
```

Once in the editor, I ran my program in the debug mode and worked, and then started code with

```
$ code
```

And it continued working fine.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: See related comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823194/cannot-find-runtime-node-on-path-visual-studio-code-and-node-js#comment136570092_38414254

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue with zsh and nvm on Linux, I fixed it by adding nvm initialization script in `~/.profile` and restart login session like this

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" 
 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm 
 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
```

Answer (score 5):

I use `/bin/zsh`, and I changed vscode to do the same, but somehow vscode still use the path from `/bin/bash`. So I created a .bash_profile file with node location in the path.

Simply run in terminal:

```
echo "PATH=$PATH
export \$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Restart vscode, and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Just relaunch your project from the termial

e.g. yourprojectdir code .

Comment: See related comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823194/cannot-find-runtime-node-on-path-visual-studio-code-and-node-js#comment136570092_38414254

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this error. Restart the PC works for me.

Comment: its irrelevant, its about your session which need to be restarted: you just have to logout then log back . no need to restart computer

Answer (score 2):

Do not launch the VS code from the start menu separately. Use

> $Code .

command to launch VS code. Now, create your file with the extension .js and Start debugging (F5) it. It will be executed.

Otherwise, restart your system and follow the same process.

Comment: See related comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823194/cannot-find-runtime-node-on-path-visual-studio-code-and-node-js#comment136570092_38414254

Answer (score 2):

The cause for me receiving this error was trying the new pre-release VSCode JS debugger.

If you opted in, change via User settings:

```
    "debug.javascript.usePreview": true|false
```

Everything in my normal configuration and integrated terminal was correct and finding executables. I wasted a lot of time trying other things!

Comment: I am using vscode insiders version 1.46.0-insider, but I had to set this to `false` in order to get the debugger to hit breakpoints. I am using the jasmine-test-explorer. Now I just need to figure out why the node version isn't being picked up from my NVM installation; instead, it is using the bundled node version with vscode.

Comment: Hmm in that case you can try specifying `runtimeVersion` to match what Node environment you're using. Others have also said launching code from the command line picks up environment more reliably, e.g. `cd project` then `code-insiders .`

Comment: `debug.javascript.usePreview` is no longer available starting from VSCode 1.60.0. Check out options on how to use the legacy debugger in [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69122112/1044637)

Answer (score 2):

(CMD+SHIFT+P)  Shell command: Install 'code' command in PATH

should do the trick!

Comment: Maybe after a restart, though restarting generally fixes this issue for me. Hopefully this is a permanent fix and I won't be required to keep restarting VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

i resolved this problem after disable `ESLint` extention.

Answer (score 1):

I am on OSX, this did not work for me:

```
code . --user-data-dir='.'
```

but this DID work:

```
code . -data-dir='.'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution according to the VS code debugging page.
This worked for my setup on Windows 10.

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Program",
    "program": "${file}"
}
```

The solution is here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Here is the launch configuration generated for Node.js debugging

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue. Did the following and it got fixed.

1. Open your computer terminal (not VSCode terminal) and type node --version to ensure you have node installed. If not, then install [node](https://nodejs.org/en/) using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).
2. Then head to your bash file (eg .bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile) and add the PATH:

```
 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm 
 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
```

3. If you have multiple bash files, you ensure to add the PATH to all of them.
4. Restart your VSCode terminal and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was more project specific. We use "Auto Reload" to run our launch.json for the backend. The error states the file path of the `runtimeExecutable` and allows you to open `launch.json`. In my launch.json case:

`"runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/functions/node_modules/.bin/nodemon"`

I tried the restarts and answers here originally but no luck, so I manually explored into my `functions/node_modules` folder and realized `.bin` was missing. I used my terminal to path into `functions` like so:

```
   cd functions

   Terminal directory path example: ( ~/OneDrive/Desktop/{project dir covered}/{project dir covered}/functions )
```

Then I did an npm install using `npm i`, and now everything is back to normal. Keep in mind, most of these answers are general fixes. If your situtation is more specific, be sure to break it down from the start. Hope this might help others!