# Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio-code

I Have installed VS Code and Node Js but getting errors when running the application. Anybody help me out please.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}},
        map: { 'app': './angular2/src/app' }
      });
      System.import('app/environment_main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
   <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH - Visual Studio Code and Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823194/cannot-find-runtime-node-on-path-visual-studio-code-and-node-js)

Comment: What's That mean @suraj?

Comment: node is not set as environment variable. check the SO link

Comment: Okay Thanks for the Help

Answer (score 1):

using cmd, navigate to the root of your project.

type: code .

remember the "." and press enter. then try to debug your project and let me know if you are facing the same issue

Comment: Adding [link](https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editor/setup/) on how to setup VSCode so that ```code .``` works