# Node binary not found in PATH by IDE, yet shows during `echo $PATH` (Ubuntu Linux)

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

VSCode shows the following alert in a prompt:

> Can't find Node.js binary "node": path does not exist. Make sure Node.js is installed and in your PATH, or set the "runtimeExecutable" in your launch.json

In terminal I see an NVM path to node:

```
$ node --version
v12.18.4

$ echo $PATH
/home/owner/.config/nvm/versions/node/v12.18.4/bin
:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin
:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
// line breaks manually added by me for readability

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

$ npm --version
6.14.6
```

Does anyone know how to fix this PATH issue?

I suspect the issue is with PATH and not VsCode but am including my launch.json below in case I'm wrong.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**",
        "node_modules"
      ],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/server.ts",
      "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/compiled/**/*.js"
      ],
      "runtimeExecutable": "node"
    }
  ]
}
```

Other Attempts to fix this

**Restarting Computer** - The PATH issue still presented

**Adding / removing runtimeExecutable k/v pair from above config file** - Also no change

Comment: This happened for me today.
Node was installed in my user path.
VS Code was running as a separate user.

Closing VS Code and opening it from the terminal as my user fixed it.

Comment: @MerkleGroot - this fixed it for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH - Visual Studio Code and Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823194/cannot-find-runtime-node-on-path-visual-studio-code-and-node-js)

Answer (score 8):

update launch.json with this

```
  "runtimeExecutable": "/usr/local/bin/node",
```

Comment: in on a unix susyem, try run `which node` to get the path of your nodeJS.  Then add the output to the launch config as shown in this answer  "runtimeExecutable": "${which node}",

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your IDE does not find Node path in your computer.

You first should find where you have Node installed, can be done using the `echo` command:

```
echo node
```

And go to the launch.json file, and update the `"runtimeExecutable"` option to the path you got here.

launch.json file, example in Visual Studio Code:

```
{
  ...
  "configurations": [
    {
      ...
      "runtimeExecutable": "insert here the path returned by echo node",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -4):

This is probably not the most elegant solution but I redundantly installed nodejs via terminal and this has fixed the PATH issue

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

The debugger is showing the path to the node binary in the subfolder of `nvm` so I'm not clear what changes were made, other than it works now.