# In the linked question, what does the op talk about regarding installing node.js in the working directory?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am a complete newbie to all this.
I tried to install node.js 4 times and then again uninstalled it every time trying different things, thinking one of them would work.
The link to the question is-[Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH - Visual Studio Code and Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823194/cannot-find-runtime-node-on-path-visual-studio-code-and-node-js)

After I typed `$node --version` in powershell terminal in VSCode (after installing node.js in C drive, defaulting to all recommended options in the setup) I get an error. I have uploaded the image of the error.
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZAlj.png)
Please tell me how to get node.js working with VSCode.

Comment: Please try entering `node --version` in the console

Comment: 1) It doesnt matter where you install node.js, 2) You should add the installation dir to the "PATH" Variable to access it from a terminal you did, with: `node --version`. After you editet the path variable (to be sure all program access the updated) close all programs and logout/login. PS: Its *not* `$node` its just `node`

Comment: @AnonymousDeeply The `PATH` Variable is a "Environment Variable", https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/ & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable

Comment: Do I have to install Chocalatey if I only want to use VSCode for JS?

Comment: @Marc TYSM for the links. and the info.

Comment: @Marc, Yes node --version worked!

Comment: Chocalatey is just a package manager for windows like apt/yum for ubuntu/rhel. No need to install it. You can download/install node directly from http://nodejs.org

Comment: @Marc Thankyou Very Much.. for helping me out here. Yes I succesfully got node working with VScode.

Answer (score 0):

To get the version of Node, just type `node --version` in the terminal without the "$".